# Laravel group by Hour from datetime Format

Tags: sql, laravel

How can I group "registrations" on my website by the hour of the day?

I have tried this but it is not working.

```
$regs = DB::table('registrations')
       ->select('createddatetime', DB::raw('COUNT(id)'))
       ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATEPART(hour, createddatetime)'), 'createddatetime')
       ->get();
```

I get an error:

> Cannot access empty property.

I'm expecting more than 0 results from the query.

Comment: add `registrations` table to answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GroupBy function to make it proper

```
$regs = DB::table('registrations')->select('createddatetime', DB::raw('COUNT(id) as count'))->get();
$regs = $regs->groupBy(function($reg){
    return date('H',strtotime($reg->createddatetime));
});
echo '<pre>';
print_r($regs);
```

Comment: createdatetime is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause error.

Answer (score 4):

If your DB is mysql, then you can do like

```
$registrationsByHour = DB::table('registrations')
            ->select(DB::raw('hour(createddatetime)'), DB::raw('COUNT(id)'))
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('hour(createddatetime)'))
            ->get();
```

Comment: I'm using Sql Server for this.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried your answer guys. But it turns out that the error was caused by Missing Alias to my raw.

```
$regs = DB::table('registrations')
   ->select('createddatetime', DB::raw('COUNT(id) as count'))
   ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATEPART(hour, createddatetime)'), 'createddatetime')
   ->get();
```

i just added the alias and it solves my problem. Nevertheless, answers are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Registration::all()->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
        return Carbon::parse($item['createddatetime'])->hour;
    });
```

Comment: This works but it's worth noting that this will perform the groupBy on the collection, so after the database query has been completed.