# Laravel Eloquent - Get a record every hour

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table that stores statistics **every 3 minutes** with a cron job.
I want to display a chart with this data but I want the chart to have an interval of 1 hour otherwise it looks ugly as hell and is too much resource demanding.
The table has the created_at and updated_at columns.

How can I do this with eloquent?

EDIT: I want to query the records from the last 24 hours but that gives me around 480 records which is too much for a chart. I'd like to have only 24 records instead (one for every hour).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want to fetch records for the past hour?

Comment: Clarify this a bit; are you looking for all data in the past hour (20 records, 3 minutes each), or are you looking to display all data (or all data for a given time period), grouped by hours? Little unclear, and potentially too broad.

Comment: To clarify: I want to query the records from the last 24 hours but that gives me around 480 records wich is too much for a chart. I'd like to have only 24 records instead (one for every hour).

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Thanks; thats much clearer. So a couple approaches; one would be to leverage the grouping in MySQL (or whatever DB you use), the other would be to use PHP/Carbon dates to handle. Give one of those a shot, and if you have a specific error, post an update. This is currently too broad, and you generally need to try something first to get help on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I tried using to groupBy() method from eloquent with no success, yet.

Comment: There's a few hits on google for "Laravel group records by hour", such as https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/count-rows-grouped-by-hours-of-the-day and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610135/laravel-group-by-hour-from-datetime-format; are any of the approaches in those questions helpful?

Comment: It was helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Tim!
For anyone reading through this later, here is the solution: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/count-rows-grouped-by-hours-of-the-day

```
Model::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay())->get()->groupBy(function($date) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('h');
});
```

Comment: This will retrieve all your records and then apply Collection's groupBy to it. If your database grows, it might become a little bit slow. You might want to apply a `where` clause that will pull records for the past 24 hours only and then work with that.

Comment: Yeah, @Mozammil is correct. For smaller tables, this is fine, but you're adding 20 records an hour, so your dataset will be **huge** after a short period of time. You definitely want to add a `->where("created_at", ...)` to your `Model` query to limit that.

Comment: Haven't thought of that, updated the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to get data 1 hours ago base on current time.

```
//Get all data for the day
$all_data = Model::where('created_at','>=',Carbon::today()->get());
//Recursive to groupBy hours
$i=1;
while ($all_data->last() != null)
{
    $hourly_data = Model::where('created_at','>=',Carbon::today()->addHours($i))->get();
    $all_data= $all_data->merge($hourly_data);
$i++
}

return $all_data;
```

Comment: Read the requirements in the question; they want all data from 24 hours ago grouped by the hour. This does not accomplish that.

Comment: This is still not right. `$data` is not even defined. So this will essentially *just* retrieve records created today.

Comment: @Mozammil MMy bad forget to update one of the variable name . Opss~